# Does c/c++ have a delay function?

Tags: c++, c

Does c/c++ have a delay/wait/sleep function?

Comment: for study purposes, i just wanna delay my program for like 1~2 seconds

Comment: are you on windows / unix / something else?

Comment: -1 you neither used the SO search nor google and both have the answer on the first results page

Comment: Search? Why? The anwser is in the question.

Comment: Ironically, this question was the first result for me when I searched for "c++ function with delay".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ does not have a sleep function. But most platforms do.

On Linux you have `sleep()` and `usleep()`. On Windows you have `Sleep()`.

You just have to include the appropriate headers to get access to them.

Comment: that's what i thought. i couldn't find one in the c/c++ libs

Answer (score 6):

The closest to a cross-platform sleep function that I know of is in boost::thread. It's called [`sleep`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.sleep).

However, if you're working on a platform where plain ol' [`sleep(unsigned int seconds)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/) is available, then I'd just use that.

Comment: I think its better to use user defined function for cross platform instead of using any third party libs.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the platform. There're [`sleep()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/Sleep/) and [`usleep()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/usleep/) for instance.

Comment: which platform is that? which header is the function defined? thx

Comment: See links. Wouldn't it make more sense if you tell us what is your platform?

Answer (score 1):

sleep()? Dunno, just an idea.

Comment: My understanding is that `sleep()` is not available for all platforms.

Comment: @DominicRodger You are right. For UNIX like OS you can use sleep() but for windows you will not find this. You need to use Sleep() instead of sleep(). That's what my answer in this thread indicated. Suggesting a possible way to port delay function for all platform. :)

Answer (score 1):

aha, you can use Sleep() in windows.it's a kernel function, in linux it is sleep(x)
x = mil-sec

Answer (score 1):

sleep is not very accurate, as it only give you seconds granularity and your process might not wake up right on the "dot".  If you want much more accurate timer. I would use select system call. both unix and windows have it.

Something like this will sleep for 10 microseconds
struct timeval tv;

tv.sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 10;
select(0,NULL,NULL,NULL,&tv);

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross platform solution. sleep() is POSIX, not standard C/C++.

You could look at a cross platform library that [provides sleep](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=360184), e.g. [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

[Source code](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/viewvc.cgi/trunk/SDL/src/thread/).

Answer (score 0):

For cross platform you can design your own Sleep function. See the example below -

```
MyClass::MySleepMethod(int milisec)
{
 #ifdef WINDOWS
 Sleep(milisec);
 #else
 sleep(milisec);
 #endif
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I asked the mighty google for it and its [first answer](http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/comp99/CS042.htm) goes like:

```
int x,y;
for(x = 0; x < 2000; x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < 2000000; y++)
    {
    }
}
```

But you have to adjust the number in for loop to your system.

```
time_t start_time, cur_time;
time(&start_time);
do
{
    time(&cur_time);
}
while((cur_time - start_time) < 3);
```

and

```
clock_t start_time, cur_time;
start_time = clock();
while((clock() - start_time) < 3 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
{
}
```

and last but not least

> There are several other functions that
>   can be used.  For Windows computers,
>   there are _ftime, Sleep(), and
>   QueryPerformanceCounter() functions,
>   as well as the sytem timer.

Comment: (it wasn't me who hit this with the -1).  The first snippet in this is a really bad way to make a delay since a) it will delay for different times on different processors and b) compiling with optimisations on will likely detect (correctly) that it does nothing and skip straight over it.

Comment: You are right, it just what google gave me. I remember using it in Turbo Pascal about 10 years ago and it worked fine ... on my machine :) Also it is a hint to you google, espacially because of the OPs user name.

Comment: It's also a bad thing because it will not sleep, it will work hard, smoking your cpu and not letting other processes take advantage of your sleep.

Comment: But the question is for a `delay function` and not a sleep function. Also this loop ways are platform independet and the OP didn't specify an OS

Comment: You might find that the first solution given (by Google) above does not even provide a 'smoking' delay, as the optimiser might 'unroll' and/or otherwise remove the loops and/or unused variables. [That will vary by compiler vendor and version, and will also depend on which of the compiler optimisation switches are selected.]

Comment: In my case, I am running on a Xilinx FPGA with a virtual microprocessor and no operating system calls. There are places where short delays are needed and a loop with calls to asm( "nop" ) are an alternative to implementing timers with interrupts and having to maintain the previous state. 
If there is a concern about a loop getting optimized out, declaring the index as volatile can help. And yes, the tick to real time must be determined by measurement on the target HW with the appropriate compiler settings.